# Do not ask for Chrome Camera permission if it was already approved through WebRTC call

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, permissions, webrtc

In our web-conference application we have Flash client through which we provide video and audio communication. Video is done though Red5 Media Server, audio is done through WebRTC.

When you are trying to access mic or camera in Flash, it will prompt the Flash Permission Window to approve the access to video and camera. However in Chrome, it will also prompt for Chrome Mic and Camera Permission. A problem with that is that Chrome Mic and Camera Permission is not very visible and user would usually miss this prompt and then complain that video doesn't work.

The solution that I was thinking about is to manually trigger Chrome Permission prompt through WebRTC call and show the arrow that will point on where to press to allow.

But even after doing that, once it comes to Flash and user approves Flash Permission Window, the Chrome Mic and Camera Permission prompt will pop up again. So it seems like Chrome is not able to remember that permission was already granted.

And the question is: is there a way to make Chrome to know that permission is already there and there is no need to ask again.

This is the function to ask for Camera permission in Chrome through SIP.js:

```
function getUserWebcamMedia(getUserWebcamMediaSuccess, getUserWebcamMediaFailure) {
if (userWebcamMedia == undefined) {
    if (SIP.WebRTC.isSupported()) {
        SIP.WebRTC.getUserMedia({audio:false, video:true}, getUserWebcamMediaSuccess, getUserWebcamMediaFailure); // Chrome permission prompt pops up on this call
    } else {
        console.log("getUserWebcamMedia: webrtc not supported");
        getUserWebcamMediaFailure("WebRTC is not supported");
    }
} else {
    console.log("getUserWebcamMedia: webcam already set");
    getUserWebcamMediaSuccess(userWebcamMedia);
}
};
```

And this is how I am accessing camera in Flash:

```
var _camera:Camera = null;
_camera = Camera.getCamera();
...
_video = new Video();       
_video.attachCamera(_camera); // Flash prompt pops up on this call
```

Sorry if the situation is not very clear. I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to store webrtc permissions is if it is over a TLS/SSL connection(HTTPS). Then chrome can store what sites were allowed or disallowed. This way, when they visit your site once and approve use of their media inputs, then they do not ever have to approve of their use again on that site.

However, since Flash and WebRTC are two different ways to grab the inputs, there is no way for permissions for one to change permissions for the other.